# 'use-client' not working in Nextjs 13.4.19

Tags: javascript, typescript, vercel, next.js13, react-server-components

It seems that 'use-client' won't work on Nextjs version 13.4.19,

`- error Error: Event handlers cannot be passed to Client Component props. <button onClick={function} type=... children=...>`

Here are the files in my next project :

`src/app/layout.tsx`

```
import type { Metadata } from 'next';
import { Inter } from 'next/font/google';
import '../styles/globals.css';

const inter = Inter({ subsets: ['latin'] });

export const metadata: Metadata = {
  title: 'Create Next App',
  description: 'Generated by create next app',
};

export default function RootLayout({
  children,
}: {
  children: React.ReactNode;
}) {
  return (
    <html lang="en">
      <body className={inter.className}>{children}</body>
    </html>
  );
}
```

`src/app/page.tsx`

```
import Button from '@/components/Button';

const Home: () => JSX.Element = () => {
  return <Button />;
};

export default Home;
```

`src/components/Button/index.tsx`

```
'use-client';

const Button = (): JSX.Element => {
  return (
    <button
      onClick={() => {
        console.log('hello');
      }}
      type="button"
    >
      hello
    </button>
  );
};

export default Button;
```

and here is my package.json

```
{
  "name": "someName",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "next dev",
    "build": "next build",
    "start": "next start",
    "lint": "next lint",
    "storybook": "storybook dev -p 6006",
    "build-storybook": "storybook build"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "next": "13.4.19",
    "react": "18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "18.2.0",
    "tailwindcss": "3.3.3"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@next/eslint-plugin-next": "^13.4.19",
    "@storybook/addon-essentials": "^7.4.1",
    "@storybook/addon-interactions": "^7.4.1",
    "@storybook/addon-links": "^7.4.1",
    "@storybook/blocks": "^7.4.1",
    "@storybook/nextjs": "^7.4.1",
    "@storybook/react": "^7.4.1",
    "@storybook/testing-library": "^0.2.0",
    "@types/node": "20.6.0",
    "@types/react": "18.2.21",
    "@types/react-dom": "18.2.7",
    "@vercel/style-guide": "^5.0.1",
    "autoprefixer": "10.4.15",
    "eslint": "8.49.0",
    "eslint-config-prettier": "^9.0.0",
    "eslint-plugin-prettier": "^5.0.0",
    "eslint-plugin-storybook": "^0.6.13",
    "postcss": "8.4.29",
    "prettier": "^3.0.3",
    "prettier-plugin-tailwindcss": "^0.5.4",
    "storybook": "^7.4.1",
    "typescript": "5.2.2"
  }
}
```

I've checked the issues on github and found this one [github](https://github.com/vercel/next.js/discussions/54196) saying to update node version.
Once I updated the node version, the issue still remains

Node version outputs `v20.6.1` in my terminal

I’ve tried the canary version of nextjs and the problem persists

Does anyone have an idea of what could be going wrong ?

Comment: It is "use client" without "-"

Comment: Did "use-client" work previously!?